# What events are supported by Phonegap/Cordova besides the ones listed in the API?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I was going through the [phonegap/cordova API documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/) and I couldn't find the `touchstart` and `touchend` events listed.

I was wondering:

- Are there any official docs for these events?
- Are there any other events that aren't listed in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap doesn't have any extra events but there are JS libraires that can do what you want you are looking for. I'm not the creator or affilate with this at all, but [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) is really neat. I used on multiple Phonegap projects. It allows tap, hold, release, swipe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This API are the official for PhoneGap.You can use the only this events that are listed into this application.But,apart from this,you are developing an PhoneGap application.So you must require javaScript and jQuery.You can use javascript and jQuery events into your application.It will works into the devices.

Also,there is an jQuery Mobile for the development of the PhoneGap application.This library is work on all the devices.You will also found `touchstart` and `touchend` events here.

Here is the link:

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: I'm aware of jquery and jQuery mobile. But this does not answer my question of any extra events which are supported by phonegap...

Comment: Ok.Then well and good.I thought if you are not familiar with jQ and jQM then its my responsibility to inform you.I thought maybe this will help you in your app development.I don't think so that any extra events apart from given in the documents are supported by the PhoneGap.Yes,you might be familiar with the PhoneGap Plugins.You can develop your own plugin for making such events that are not supported by the PhoneGap.

Comment: Welcome @hitautodestruct-If i found such events then i will inform you friend.Yes there is an also one site available for PhoneGap developers.You can go through this : http://phonegap-tips.com/

Comment: You do not need to use jQuery to build an app with Cordova (Phonegap). It might help, but it is just another JavaScript library - there are many different ones available to help build your app.